# How can i get data from Wordpress API?

Tags: wordpress, flutter, dart

Help me please!
I have a link http://cs48365.tmweb.ru/api/get_posts/. This link must give data from Wordpress site.
I want ta have a code which will give me a list of news with the title and image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Http Pacakge to get the data convert it to your model and then use the data in your app.

import the pacakge

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
```

then use it

```
var url = 'http://cs48365.tmweb.ru/api/get_posts/';

  // Await the http get response, then decode the json-formatted response.
  var response = await http.get(url);
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    var jsonResponse = convert.jsonDecode(response.body);
    var posts= jsonResponse['posts'];
  } else {
    print('Request failed with status: ${response.statusCode}.');
  }
```

#### References

- [Http Package](https://pub.dev/packages/http)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Now i am trying it but i have an error in this line
var jsonResponse = convert.jsonDecode(response.body); 

Undefined name 'convert'.
Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the 


The package convert i installed.

Comment: @tamerlan676 import the following `import 'dart:convert' as convert;`

Comment: Well done! I can get a data in my console, but now i want to view it in my screen. What should i do? I have a file Post with my constructors and objects (title, image,) 

`factory Post.fromJSON(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Post(
      id: json['id'],
      title: json['title']['rendered'],
      content: json['content']['rendered'],
        image: json['thumbnail'],
      excerpt: json['excerpt']['rendered'],
    );`